# Was the drink offering poured into fire?

Tags: korban

What is the possibility that the drink offering was poured into the altar of sacrifice?

Comment: Which drink offering?

Comment: the one of the day

Comment: Do you mean into as opposed to onto?

Comment: Was it poured into the fire http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-D1WAFzgy_yU/VF0VNRGJ1eI/AAAAAAAAOa0/hmxHH1Jj7kg/s1600/The%2BBrazen%2BAltar%2Bof%2BSacrifice%2B-%2BCopy.jpg

Comment: @Chatzkel, the wine libation brought with the Korban Tamid.

Comment: In the case of one who donated wine by itself as an offering there is a different in Zevachim 91b and Menachos 74b if it was poured directly onto the fire or into the holes on the bottom of the altar. However wine and water offerings that were brought with other sacrifices always went to the holes on the bottom.

Comment: If it was poured into bowls, and the fire consumed it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it was poured into a special cup on the alter with a hole in the bottom leading to a pit underneath.

[Succah 48a-b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.48a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> נִיסּוּךְ הַמַּיִם כֵּיצַד
>
> With regard to the rite of water libation performed in the Temple during the Festival, how was it performed?
>
> שְׁנֵי סְפָלִים שֶׁל כֶּסֶף הָיוּ שָׁם רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר שֶׁל סִיד הָיוּ אֶלָּא שֶׁהָיוּ מוּשְׁחָרִין פְּנֵיהֶם מִפְּנֵי הַיַּיִן וּמְנוּקָּבִין כְּמִין שְׁנֵי חוֹטָמִין דַּקִּין (וְאֶחָד) מְעוּבֶּה וְאֶחָד דַּק כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם כָּלִין בְּבַת אַחַת מַעֲרָבוֹ שֶׁל מַיִם מִזְרָחוֹ שֶׁל יַיִן
>
> There were two silver basins there into which he poured the water. Rabbi Yehuda said: They were limestone basins, but they would blacken due to the wine and therefore looked like silver. The two basins were perforated at the bottom with two thin perforated nose-like protrusions. One of the basins, used for the wine libation, had a perforation that was broad, and one, used for the water libation, had a perforation that was thin, so that the flow of both the water and the wine, which do not have the same viscosity, would conclude simultaneously. The basin to the west of the altar was for water, and the basin to the east of the altar was for wine.

[Succah 49a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.49a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> תַּנְיָא אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר בַּר צָדוֹק לוּל קָטָן הָיָה בֵּין כֶּבֶשׁ לַמִּזְבֵּחַ בְּמַעֲרָבוֹ שֶׁל כֶּבֶשׁ וְאַחַת לְשִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה פִּרְחֵי כְהוּנָּה יוֹרְדִין לְשָׁם וּמְלַקְּטִין מִשָּׁם יַיִן קָרוּשׁ שֶׁדּוֹמֶה לְעִיגּוּלֵי דְבֵילָה
>
> It was taught in a baraita that Rabbi Elazar bar Tzadok said: There was a small gap between the ramp and the altar west of the ramp, and once in seventy years young priests would descend there and gather from there the congealed wine left over from the libations that set over time, which resembled round cakes of dried and pressed figs.

Comment: Was this also done during the 'Exodus'? It wasn't described in the building of the altar.

Comment: I assume so, but I don't have a source for that.

Comment: @Mordechai most, but not all, assume nesachim only started upon entry to the land, see zevachim 111

Comment: @DoubleAA, always the nitpicker. But we assume there were cups on the alter built by Moshe, and not just in the Second Temple, right?

Comment: @DoubleAA Rashi Kiddushin 37b says even according to Reb Yishmael who says they didn't have it in the midbar, agrees that korbanos tzibbur did have it.  Since the question was referring to korban Tamid, almost all agree there was nisachim in the midbar for that

Comment: @Chatzkel I concede. Even Ramban, who thinks there weren't musafim, agrees there was nesachim with the tamid https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%98%D7%95 Shkoyach

Comment: The Talmud Zevachim 62A mentions that the base of the altar was present in all versions, in the desert, Shiloh and in the Mikdash. It is derived from the words "the base of the altar". The Talmud on 61B mentions that in the first temple (and presumably the Mishkan as well) had a bowel near the base to catch the wine, while only in the second temple did they introduce the idea of hollowing out underneath. If so, it's not so far fetched that it was included in the Mizbeach Hanechoshes as well